# Trouble installing Clickatell Php Library

Tags: php, clickatell

I'm trying to install the clickatell php library after this instruction:

https://github.com/arcturial/clickatell

But so far i was only able to install composer.

They say: this library uses composer and can be acquired using the following in your `composer.json` file.

```
{
    "require": {
        "arcturial/clickatell": "*"
    }
}
```

So I have to add this to the composer json file? Then require the json file in my php script? I've no idea what to do next. Any help would be great.

Comment: Maybe start reading about `composer` first?

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

Comment: After adding the line to your composer file, you need to run a composer update. Have a read through the link @Ostin posted below your question; that will show you how to start using composer. It's quite useful once you know how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in your project root, run the following:

**create a composer.json file with the following contents:**

```
{
    "name": "your/project",
    "description": "project description",
    "require": {
        "arcturial/clickatell": "*"
    }
}
```

**php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php**

This will download a file called composer.phar

**php composer.phar install**

This will install the dependencies you specified in your composer.json file. Once complete, your project will now have a folder called "vendor".

**Include the "vendor/autoload.php" file in your script**

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

...

Now you should be able to use the library as specified in the documentation.